# NSDocument - setting a reasonable starting location for the window

Tags: nsdocument

I'm playing about with the most recent NSDocument in a Swift document-based-app. One thing that's a bit odd is that the starting location for a new window is near the bottom of the screen.

Playing with the Storyboard a bit, its not clear how to use the built-in settings to come up with a reasonable "near the top" selection - the setting moves up from the bottom, not down from the top, so the position would change depending on the screen size?

I assume there's a position mechanism I can hook, but it's not obvious in the shell code that's supplied. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X coordinate system is flipped in contrast to iOS. So the 0,0 is the bottom left corner.

You can calculate the position of your window in similar manner (any screen size)

```
  CGFloat width = NSWidth([self.window screen].frame); 
  CGFloat height = NSHeight([self.window screen].frame);
  [self.window setFrame:NSMakeRect(100, height - 100, width, height) display:YES];
```

Most easiest is to set initial height to 900 and forget about it and enable window restoration -> this will cause to open the window where it previously was and this is where it user wants.

Select your window in Storyboard. And fill initial position coordinates
[image: initial position]

Comment: I like the "forget about it" bit, because that does seem like the best solution. Forgotten!

Comment: Use checkbox for restorable window. Fill autosave name and put this code into your appdidfinishlaunching [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@YES forKey:@"NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows"]; The most cleanest place to put is inside registerDefaults ;)